# JFrame serialisation with LookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, serialization, look-and-feel

I am trying to serialize a JFrame containing a JDesktopPane with several JInternalFrames.
I encountered a problem with the LookAndFeel because for any reason it is not possible to serialize a Swing component with a to the CrossPlatform LnF different one.
So I wrote this test program in order to figure out my possibilites:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    try {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setBounds(200,200,200,200);
        JTree tree = new JTree();
        f.add(tree);
        f.setVisible(true);

        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                   UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(f);

        ObjectOutputStream oop = new ObjectOutputStream(
                   new FileOutputStream(new File("test.serialized")));
        oop.writeObject(f);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This didn't work for two reasons:

1. I am not able to serialize the frame and the contained tree. Just the tree is fine but just when
2. I set the LookAndFeel to cross platform in the first place and create my tree afterwards.

Any idea how to fix this?

EDIT:
Sorry for making this not clear:
I am NOT trying to serialize the LnF or something like that.
The LnF doesnt want me to serialize the Frame.

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.apple.laf.AquaTreeUI
```

And on top of that i am not able to serialize a Frame that contains a Tree.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.InternalError: incorrect component
```

Comment: The implementation of the JDesktopPane likely includes some LnF components, which would be unserializable.

In general, you'd be better off saving the state of interest in some other manner, and writing code to recreate the UI based on that saved state.

Comment: Why do you want to serialize a Swing component? Sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue013a.html). Is the implementation proposed by @SoboLAN.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying is not possible. When you serialize the JFrame object, the LnF is not serialized in any way. That is because the JFrame keeps no memory of this. What LnF is used is stored elsewhere...

What I would do is wrap the JFrame in another object, let's say MyGUI. Inside that, I would store the LnF (as a String for example) in a private field. In the end, serialize MyGUI and, at deserialization, you have the LnF nice and intact and you can set it again.

Comment: my problem is not that i WANT to serialize the LnF. I just want to serialize the JFrame and the contained elements but LnF doesn't want me to do that: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.apple.laf.AquaTreeUI

Comment: @maximilian009 Well, both JFrame and JTree classes are serializable (according to the documentation) so... this is a bit weird...